# Where does the `Dism /online /Get-Features` get the list of features from?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, reverse-engineer

Where does the `Dism /online /Get-Features` read the list of features from? For example: which files or directories.

Comment: What features show when you run it? I would guess this is based on features in the initial Windows image, but I don't know where it stores or gets that list.

Comment: I honestly spent way too long researching this (out of my own curiosity) just after you posted this and couldn't come up with a *definitive* answer myself.  The response I received from ChatGPT *seemed* to point in the right direction, but I could never verify it, and I'd never post anything that ChatGPT says on an obscure topic like this without some *extreme* verification.  My goal was to find the language strings (`.MUI` files, I believe) that had the names of the optional features, but I never tracked them down.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that it finds the names of the packages in the image.
If you don't specify a package name or path, all features in the image will be listed.

*/PackageName* is a package in an image. You can use */DISM Get-Packages* to see the package names in an image.
*/PackagePath* can point to either a .cab file or a folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Tyramizou This might not answer the question because the question is asking which exact files/directories inside the image. It's already implied in the question that the files are in the online (/Online) image.